# Installing docker-compose-plugin on amazon linux 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to install docker-compose-plugin onto Amazon Linux 2, so that "docker compose" acts more like "docker-compose" would. [As I understand, the latter is deprecated] I can't find any instructions and the obvious approach (treat it like Centos 7) does not work at all - the basic way docker is installed on Amazon Linux 2 is very different.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a bash script to install latest docker compose plugin for all users on  amazon linux 2:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/
sudo curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 2):

I did find the answer to this, or at least one that works seemingly well:

- Look at the plugin repo https://github.com/docker/compose and find the latest release (assuming you want up to date)
- Copy the URL for docker-compose-linux-x86_64
- Go to the machine and do "curl -L -o docker-compose URL", replace URL as appropriate
- chmod a+x docker-compose
- sudo mv docker-compose /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/

If you do "docker compose help" it should look like docker-compose used to output.

Answer (score 1):

if you want `docker compose v2` or `docker compose plugin`, just run below.

(note: suit for `CentOS7`or`Amazon Linux`or`amzn`)

```bash
sudo curl -L https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-compose-plugin-2.6.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm -o ./compose-plugin.rpm
sudo yum install ./compose-plugin.rpm -y
```

more package, see `https://download.docker.com/linux/`